# mysql syntax error

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I wrote this simple query statement:

```
INSERT INTO merchants 
('firstName','lastName') 
VALUES 
('Bob','Smith')
```

Sounds very simple but I keep getting this error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''firstName','lastName'  ) 
VALUES 
('Bob','Smith'  )' at line 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes from around firstName and lastName:

```
INSERT INTO merchants 
(firstName,lastName) 
VALUES 
('Bob','Smith')
```

Column names are identifiers, and as such are not quoted.

**Edit:**  Column names *can* be quoted using backticks (`), but this is only necessary if you have column names that contain special characters or column names that match MySQL keywords.

Comment: If you have to quote the column names use backticks (`) in Mysql.

Comment: I'm guessing you might have been copying the syntax from somewhere and mistaken the backticks (`) that can be used to delimit column or table names from the single quotes (') that delimit string literals.

Comment: Thank you, Kris.  I've added that note to the answer.  You're welcome, netrox.